# Paypal - Update Client ID for Past Subscriptions

Tags: javascript, wordpress, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

Previously, I used Paypal Subscription links on my website, clicking which, users can go to Paypal payment page, pay the amount there and become subscriber.

Now, I want to receive **webhooks**, whenever my subscriber updates or cancels his subscription. Therefore, am using following code to render Paypal buttons via which users can now buy subscriptions. I have setup corresponding webhooks against the below mentioned `client-id` in My Apps section in Paypal. This is all working for new subscriptions.

```
<div id="paypal-button-container-P-XXX"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXXX&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'subscribe'
        },
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                /* Creates the subscription */
                plan_id: 'P-XXX'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            alert(data.subscriptionID);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-P-XXX'); // Renders the PayPal button
</script>
```

I want to know, whether there is a way so that I can setup or receive webhooks for my old subscribers as well, which subscribed through the Subscriber Plan link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriptions are permanently tied to the Client ID they were created with.

You can subscribe to webhooks for that app's Client ID in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Verification of such webhooks will be different, so depending on your verfication method (if any) you should send such webhooks to a different URL to be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Problem is I don't know, for which client id those links were created with. Can you tell how can I know the client id of those links?

Comment: If you get button code via https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans , the client ID should be in the sdk src line

Comment: Yes for button code, I know the client id. I want to know the client-id (if any) for the direct billing links.

Comment: Generate a button for the Plan in question.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, lots of customers are already subscribed via old links. We wanted to receive hooks for those subscriptions.

Comment: Do the "old links" (whatever that means) correspond to current PayPal Subscriptions, that have a Plan ID? If so, generate a button for them, or use an old existing button, whatever. The client ID will be there, in the button. If these "old links" do not use the current version of PayPal Subscriptions, subscribe to classic NVP/SOAP API webhooks in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: By old link, I mean following link, to become subscriber:
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/billing/plans/subscribe?plan_id=P-74G86582FM9500227MIPNH6A

Comment: That uses a plan ID. Create a button for it in https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans copy the client ID from the button. Create a Webhook for the REST App the client ID corresponds to.